# Modify a repeating value in a textarea form by adding a counter

Tags: php, html

This is a problem related to adding a counter when renaming a value with the same name.

I have a form with a textarea where you can write text inside. Inside the textarea, the writer can write the word *foto* which must follow a particular path when sending the form. I specify that the written text will end up in a txt file.

I created a code that replaces the word `*foto*` with `"<img src=\"img/foto$y.jpg\">` assuming that each word `*foto*` is replaced in `"<img src=\"img/foto1. jpg\">, "<img src=\"img/foto2.jpg\">` in the txt file after submitting the form...

Instead I find that the file is generated with n.2 `"<img src=\"img/foto1.jpg\">` without increasing the counter (1-2-3 etc... based on the number of photos).

In the code `$vfoto` is the number of photos the user has decided to upload. `$v5` is the article.

Html:

```
<form>
<textarea name="post_content" id="article"</textarea>
</form>
```

Text write Textarea box:

```
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>*foto*</p>
    <p>*foto*</p>
```

PHP:

```
$v5 = $_POST["post_content"];


if ($vfoto > 0){
    $y = 1;
    for ($x = 1; $x <= $vfoto; $x++) {
     $v5 = str_ireplace("<p>*foto*</p>","<img src=\"img/foto$y.jpg\" 
     class=\"img_article_box\">",$v5);
     $y++;
    }
    $myfile = fopen("provafile.txt","w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($myfile, html_entity_decode($v5));
    fclose($myfile);
}
```

The result I would expect is:

```
<p>test</p>
<img src="img/foto1.jpg" class="img_article_box">
<img src="img/foto2.jpg" class="img_article_box">
```

Comment: Remember that `str_ireplace()` replaces *all* the instances of the pattern.  If you just want to replace the first one, you could use `preg_replace()` with a limit instead (or use a callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple do this, use regex and the prebuild php function to handle replacements,

```php
//Your input
$text = $_POST["post_content"];

// Regex Pattern
$pattern = '/\*foto\*/';

// Index counter
$replacementIndex = 1;

// Replaced Text
$replacedText = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($matches) use (&$replacementIndex) {
    $replacement = "<img src=\"img/foto" . $replacementIndex . ".jpg\" class=\"img_article_box\">";
    $replacementIndex++;
    return $replacement;
}, $text);

// Result after replacements
echo $replacedText;
```

#### Input

```
<p>Test</p>
<p>*foto*</p>
<p>*foto*</p>
```

#### Output

```
<p>Test</p>
<p><img src="img/foto1.jpg" class="img_article_box"></p>
<p><img src="img/foto2.jpg" class="img_article_box"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `preg_replace` function with the limit argument (fourth parameter) to replace just one instance of the text. This would allow you to replace the next instance in the text.

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['post_content']) ){
    $v5 = $_POST['post_content'];

    preg_match_all("@\*foto\*@s", $v5, $foto_matches);

    if( $foto_matches[0] ){
        foreach($foto_matches[0] as $k=>$foto_match){
            $find = preg_quote($foto_match);

            $replacement = '<img src="img/foto'.($k+1).'.jpg" class="img_article_box">';
            
            $v5 = preg_replace("@".$find."@", $replacement, $v5, 1);
        }
    }

    $myfile = fopen("provafile.txt","w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    
    fwrite($myfile, html_entity_decode($v5));
    
    fclose($myfile);
}?>

<form method="post">
<textarea name="post_content" id="article"></textarea>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```